# Quarkus: CDI not working when using Google Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions, cdi, quarkus

I followed the [QUARKUS - GOOGLE CLOUD FUNCTIONS](https://quarkus.io/guides/gcp-functions) tutorial, but dependency injection doesn't seem to be working in that context as any `@Inject`'ed object is `null` at runtime:

- both while [testing locally](https://quarkus.io/guides/gcp-functions#testing-locally),
- and running on GCP too.

Downloading and running [the tutorial solution](https://quarkus.io/guides/gcp-functions#solution*) gives the same result for me.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is usually caused by using the wrong entry point inside the `gcloud` command.

You **must** use the Quarkus provided function and not your function as the entry point class from your `gcloud` command.

This is descibed in this part of the guide https://quarkus.io/guides/gcp-functions#build-and-deploy-to-google-cloud, maybe we need to make it clearer.

For a background function, use `gcloud functions deploy my-function --entry-point --entry-point=io.quarkus.gcp.functions.QuarkusBackgroundFunction ...`

For an HTTP function, use `gcloud functions deploy my-function --entry-point --entry-point=io.quarkus.gcp.functions.QuarkusHttpFunction ...`

The Quarkus function will bootstrap the framework (including CDI), search for your function and inject dependencies in it.